# IImebra code in C++ app with Qt gives malloc: *** error for object xxxxxx: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, qt, malloc, jpeg, dicom

I'm trying to convert dicom `.dcm` file to `.jpeg` using Imebra in C++ app using Qt Creator as dev environment.

I've downloaded Imebra and was able to run Qt project example for Dicom2Jpeg conversion successfully. But when I tried to copy same code to my C++ app it failed to run with following error msg:

```
malloc: *** error for object xxxxxx: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I have followed steps on adding Imebra files to my project as it was shown on Imebra site. Also used their qt project as example. My `main.cpp` open dicom file, then loads it to dataset, then calls my dialog window. It crashes on loading dataset.

```
#include "QApplication.h"
#include "QHBoxLayout.h"
#include "mydialog.h"
#include "iostream.h"

include "library/imebra/include/imebra.h"
int main( int argc, char ** argv ){

    using namespace puntoexe;
    ptr<stream> readStream(new stream);
    readStream->openFile("/pathToDcmFile/test.dcm",std::ios_base::in);

    ptr<streamReader> reader(new streamReader(readStream));

    ptr<imebra::codecs::codecFactory> 
    cFactory(imebra::codecs::codecFactory::getCodecFactory());
    ptr<imebra::dataSet> tdataSet;
    tdataSet=cFactory->load(reader,2048);

    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(images);

    QApplication a( argc, argv );

    MyDialog md;
    md.show();

    return a.exec();
```

}

Deeper debugging showed that source of error is in `JpegCodec.cpp` file `readStream()` function when checking JpegSignature to see if it's in wrong format with resulting internal PUNTOEXE error "detected a wrong format".

Interesting thing is that while running same test dcm file using given dicom2jpeg example (which has exact same code of opening file and loading it) gives no errors and converts to jpeg successfully. So I know it's not the file issue, but the way imebra code is integrated into my C++ app.

My dev environment: macbook pro with Lion OS, Qt Creator, Qt project, C++ code, ITK library added, Imebra files are completely integrated as part of the Qt project.

So, my question is how do I work/link/reference/call Imebra functionality in Qt project? Am I forgetting to link something, or some object is not instantiated/deleted on time?

Any ideas are highly appreciated,

Evushka

Solution: As it was suggested I have changed codec factory to dicm factory and it fixed the problem. My new code is given below.

```
imebra::codecs::dicomCodec* pTmp = new imebra::codecs::dicomCodec();

ptr<stream> readStream(new stream);
readStream->openFile(argv[0],std::ios_base::in);

ptr<streamReader> reader(new streamReader(readStream));

ptr<imebra::dataSet> tdataSet;
tdataSet=pTmp->read(reader,2048);

delete pTmp;
```

Comment: Only a magician would be able to answer this without seeing any code.

Comment: 1. You haven't asked a question.  2. I agree with Nikos.  Nobody can help you without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. I just added my code. I had to really simplified it. I hope ppl who worked with Imebra will be able shed some light on this issue.

Comment: You can replace the miscellaneous new's, `ptr<>`: `imebra::dataSet* dSet = ...`. Sure you'll get memory leaks for the time trying.

Comment: @ Joop: Not sure what "replace miscellaneous new's" means, but I've tried to changed it to more detailed statements. See changes in code above. To no avail, same error.

Comment: I've noticed that Imebra uses CriticalSection and Locks heavily. Maybe this source of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "detected a wrong format" is thrown because the library checks the file against all the file formats, and since you are reading a Dicom file then the Jpeg code throws an exception, but this should be recovered by the codec factory. You may be a victim of this bug:  https://bitbucket.org/puntoexe/imebra/issue/89/ which prevents the Dicom codec from registering statically at startup, causing the factory codec to skip the Dicom codec entirely. The bug report also contains a workaround.

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU! I have changed codec factory to dicom codec and it works like a charm.

Comment: @PaoloBrandoli How can I display image on iPhone using Imebra library with Environment XCode and iPhone 5 device ?